# Why is my javascript add class to turn an image display to none not working?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid instructions">
    <img src="chick2.png">
    <img class="img1" src="dice6.png">
    <img class="img2" src="dice6.png">
    <img class="img3 threeChoices" src="dice6.png">
    <img class="img4 fourChoices" src="dice6.png">
    <img src="chick1.png">
  </div>
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
    </div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')
links.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
    document.getElementById('dropdownMenu1').innerHTML = `${numberOfChoices}<span class="caret"></span>`
    console.log(numberOfChoices)

    // Showing Correct Number of Boxes
    if (numberOfChoices === 2) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".img3").classList.add(".invisible");
    }
  })
})
```

and this is the css:

```
.invisible{display: none;}
```

If 2 is selected on the dropdown button, I want image with class img3 to be disappear. Why is it not working can someone help please thanks in advance

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".img3")` returns a **list** of zero or more elements. You have to iterate through the list and perform the `classList` changes on each one individually.

Comment: Or use document.`querySelector` if you only want the first hit for this class.

Comment: thanks all I will try querySelector now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your codeI found out that you had three issues that prevented the image to be hidden when adding the class.

First is that you where comparing a `string` with an `int`, son that is the first change you need to do.

Second you were calling the `querySelectorAll(".img3")` which prevents you from getting the `classList`property before doing a `forEach()` on the result, so you need to change it to `querySelector(".img3")`.

And the last issue is that you were adding `.invisible` class which would look like `<div class=".invisible">` and you should just add the name of the class `invisible`.

Here is the code with the fixes:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')
links.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
    document.getElementById('dropdownMenu1').innerHTML = `${numberOfChoices}<span class="caret"></span>`
    console.log(numberOfChoices)

    // Showing Correct Number of Boxes
    if (numberOfChoices === "2") { // <------- fix 1
      var element = document.querySelector(".img3"); // <------ Fix 2
      element.classList.add("invisible"); // <------ Fix 3
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid instructions">
  <img src="chick2.png">
  <img class="img1" src="dice6.png">
  <img class="img2" src="dice6.png">
  <img class="img3 threeChoices" src="dice6.png">
  <img class="img4 fourChoices" src="dice6.png">
  <img src="chick1.png">
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
</div>
```

------------------- UPDATE FOR JQUERY ------------------------

If you would like to use JQuery and tied up the code a little more here is the changes on the code you will need to make. In this code you will first need to add JQuery to your code as a script, be it pulling the js from the cloud or by downloading the latest version.

Once JQuery is working we would need to change the way we get the elements from using `document.querySelector('selector')` to `$('selector')`, which is the way JQuery handles element selection.

As JQuery does not differentiate the way to get one and all elements, the code works different. If it finds more than one element it handles the return as an array that you can work directly without calling `forEach` or `each`. So here is the second change.

The last change is the one you already suggested on the comments. To be able to select various elements with different classes or ids just use the `,` separator inside the selector and then the `addClass` method.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#list li', function(event) {
  let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
  $('#dropdownMenu1').html(numberOfChoices + "<span class='caret'></span>")
  console.log(numberOfChoices);

  // Showing Correct Number of Boxes
  if (numberOfChoices === "2") {
    $(".img3, .img4").addClass("invisible");
  }
})
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script> <!-- IMPORTANT here you add jquery from the cloud -->
<div class="container-fluid instructions">
  <img src="chick2.png">
  <img class="img1" src="dice6.png">
  <img class="img2" src="dice6.png">
  <img class="img3 threeChoices" src="dice6.png">
  <img class="img4 fourChoices" src="dice6.png">
  <img src="chick1.png">
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
</div>
```

Comment: if I want to make img3 and img4 disappear, is there a way to select them both and add .invisible class to both of them in the same line? Thanks

Comment: Nvm I got it I will use   $('.img3, .img4').addClass('invisible') thanks all

Comment: If you want to go with JQuery you could even improve all your code, so you can have a very small amount of code, not use `querySelector` and change `el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {` to `el.onClick( function() {`

Comment: Actually that doesn't work, it shows 'index.js:28 Uncaught Type Error: el.onClick is not a function
    at index.js:28
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:27 '

Comment: You are completely right is not `onClick` but ´$('selector').on('click' function() { })` None the less I updated the answer with the complete change and it is working.